# Android TCP socket: How to set a listener for incomming/received data

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm developing a android client which communicates with a server using TCP protocol. everything is okay except for receiving data from the server. the only way i know for now, is to periodically check if there is something to read, an that's bad. is there any listener, callback or any way to get informed when the client receives a message so that i can run a method to read and process it ?

Here is my code

```
class QTcpSocket implements Runnable {

    private String ip="";
    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    private DataInputStream dataInputStream;

    public QTcpSocket(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

      public void setIp(String ip) {
          this.ip = ip;
      }

      public String getIp() {
          return this.ip;
      }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            socket = new Socket(this.ip, this.port);

            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String response = dataInputStream.readUTF();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {

            byte[] buffer= message.getBytes();
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {

            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isClosed() {
        return socket.isClosed();
    }
}
```